# Change ALL data in an SQL tables column to = 120

Tags: mysql

I need to change EVERY entry in a tables 'confirmations' column to 120.

..something like
update * from blocks set confirmed = 1

What is it that i can try?

http://picpaste.com/Untitled-1-T2bgNu9W.gif

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `blocks` SET `confirmations`=120
```

Comment: @Bob - a Thank-you comment doesn't help the answerer. With just a bit more rep, you'll be able to upvote the answer.